# UML: how to implement Association class in Java

Tags: java, associations, uml

I have this UML Association class. Note that: horizontal line is a solid line and the vertical line is a dashed line.

```
 ---------                  ---------
|         |*(a)        *(b)|         |
| CLASS   |________________|  CLASS  |
|STUDENT  |     |          |  COURSE |
 ---------      |           ---------
                |*(c)
          ______|______
         |             |
         |             |
         |  CLASS      |
         | TRANSCRIPT  |
         |_____________|
```

I understand this relationship but I have met some problems when implement this UML to code. I can implement relation between class `Student` and class `Course` to code. Here is my code:

```
class Student {
  Vector<Course> b;
}

class Course {
   Vector<Student> a;
}
```

But, at class `Transcript`, I don't understand so much, how to use this class in code. Is it the property of both class `Student` and `Course`. So, if that's true then the code will be:

```
class Student {
  Vector<Course> b;
  Vector<Transcript> c;
}

class Course {
  Vector<Student> a;
  Vector<Transcript> c;
}
```

Is it true? If this is wrong, please teach me how to implement this UML.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is transcript really an attribute of a class? I think each student has a transcript, and each transcript could have a vector of classes..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all, don't use Vector, as it's an old class that shouldn't be used anymore for more than 10 years. Use either a `Set` or a `List`.

If the `Transcript` class contains information about the way a student attends a course (for example, the date of its subscription to the course), you could implement it like this:

```
class Student {
    Set<Transcript> transcripts;
}

class Transcript {
    Student student;
    Course course;
    Date subscriptionDate;
}

class Course {
    Set<Transcript> transcripts;
}
```

That doesn't prevent you from providing a method in Student that returns all his courses:

```
public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    Set<Course> result = new HashSet<Course>();
    for (Transcript transcript : transcripts) {
        result.add(transcript.getCourse());
    }
    return result;
}
```

If `Transcript` doesn't contain any information, then it's probably there to model how these classes would be mapped in database tables, where the only way to have a many-to-many association between two tables is to use a join table holding the IDs of the two associated tables.

Comment: Is two way association necessary? That is, is it necessary to add student in course and course in student in all association cases?

Comment: No, it's not. But the OP wanted this bidirectinality.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is very old but I have a way more convenient than embedding n..1 relations in the association class :

```
public class Transcript {
    //Transcript's properties
} 

public class Course {

    private Map<Student, Transcript> transcriptsByStudent;
}

public class Student {

    private Map<Course, Transcript> transcriptsByCourse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on, on your model you denote multiplicity on the association class. This is unnecessary because the association class **IS** the association itself, and the multiplicity relationship of the original two classes will satisfy.