# Modeling relationships with domain models

Tags: node.js, architecture, software-design

In my system, an **User** can be member of a **Team**.

I got a domain model called **Team** which contains `id`, `name`, `member_count` and `is_channel`. So when I fetch teams in the repository I retrieve the **Team** domain model.

How would I model the relation between a **User** and a **Team**? Because when talking about the relation I don’t care about the `member_count` and `is_channel` from the **Team** model. I even have extra data in the relation which is a `role_type`.

Should I create a domain model for the relation called **TeamScope** or something? That contains `id`, `user_id`, `team_id`, `role_type`?

Comment: Are you confusing **domain object** (or **conceptual class**) with **domain model**? `Team` is a *conceptual class* in the *domain model*. I'm similarly confused by the last question, "Should I create a domain model..." There's one domain model, but it contains classes and associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments on your question regarding your use of terms (model, class, association). I'm assuming you are misusing them when I wrote my answer.

> How would I model the relation between a `User` and a `Team`? Because when talking about the relation I don’t care about the `member_count` and `is_channel` from the `Team` model (sic). I even have extra data in the relation which is a `role_type`.

You could use an [association class](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/) in your domain model to represent this.

[image]

`Membership` can capture the `role_type`, which really is linked to the association as you have figured out.

`member_count` is represented with a `/` at the start, indicating that you'll derive its value from the multiplicity (it's a count of the number of members associated with the team).

You tagged [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) in your question, so I'm going to point to [how to implement association classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443944/1168342) (not exactly your case, but in Node.js it should be easy to apply).

Comment: How would I combine Team and Membership in a later stage? I do not want to create two seperate queries for this..

Comment: If you don't mind users only being on one team at a time, and a role that makes no sense if a user is not associated with a team, you could remove Membership and put role in User. Domain models are geared at capturing the correct requirements of a business process, not necessarily about making the queries simpler. If a user can be on several teams at the same time, it's more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost definitely model a TeamMember object which contains both a link to the User, a link to the Team, and the role the user plays on that team.

Teams have a list of TeamMembers, Users have a list of TeamMembers.  Teams have a MemberCount (not sure if this is static, or dynamic from the count of TeamMembers), and I have no idea what is_channel means...